# How to restrict saving password for visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, passwords, browser

I am using the following field which lets the user to enter password.But when the user logs in for the next time I dont want the browser to suggest password.Is it possible to handle it in visualforce page?

```
 Enter Password to add filters :
 <apex:inputSecret value="{!password}" id="theSecretInput"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

After digging into this situation, the major browsers have all agreed to ignore the autocomplete attribute for `input type="password"` fields. It's considered a security enhancement. You might consider some of the workarounds mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369), but there's no guarantee the major vendors won't eventually catch on and fix that hole, too.

Also, see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms533486(v=vs.85).aspx), [Mozilla Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=956906), and [Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=370363#c7).

---

You should be able to do so via HTML pass-through on the form:

```
<apex:form html-autocomplete="off">
    <!-- later -->
    <apex:inputSecret value="{!password}" id="theSecretInput" />
```

Generally speaking, you should probably not do this, because being able to auto-complete passwords allows users to have more complex passwords without resorting to Post-IT Notes, which facilitates more secure accounts.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox, But I am getting the following error"Cannot override attribute 'autocomplete' on component <apex:inputSecret>" since my previous password value is being stored in there

Comment: @Pri It looks like you can only do so on the form. I'll edit.

Comment: Yeah,I am not getting the error now,But still its asking me whether to update password with the new one??

Comment: @Pri Most likely because the password is already saved. Try deleting it from your history and try again.

Comment: @Pri Nevermind. Apparently, all major browsers now ignore autocomplete="off" for password fields. Primarily because of what I previously said: not allowing a user to save a password is detrimental to security. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms533486(v=vs.85).aspx), [Mozilla Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=956906), and [Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=370363#c7). There's a new spec on the horizon, though, that being `autocomplete="new-password"`, which might do what you want (or not).